# Merging rows in Excel with common column (A) and keeping largest value in column (D)

Tags: excel, merge, bigdata, multiple-columns

So I am trying to find a way to merge the two rows together based on 1st column and keeping the larger value in the 4th column. Would any one guide me on how to achieve that?

[image: Screenshot for illustration]

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you heard of VBA?

Comment: Try Pivot Tables combined with filters with max condition. It's exactly what you need